# How to prevent pager_default_initialize from getting initialized?

Tags: paging

I'm calling this function [pager_default_initialize](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/pager_default_initialize/7) on a certain condition. But once this function gets called, it initializes default pager everywhere I `return theme('pager')`.

What I want is

```
if(condition == TRUE)
pager_default_initialize($total, $limit, $element = 0) get executed
theme('pager') works!
if(condition == FALSE)
pager_default_initialize($total, $limit, $element = 0) not get executed
theme('pager') should stop work. I don't want pager when condition is FALSE.
```

but problem is once `condition == TRUE` gets satisfied, I got pager everywhere.

**Any  way to uninitialize this pager function on certain condition?**

Comment: Where are you calling your code?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to override `theme_pager()`:

```
function MYTHEME_pager($variables) {
  if (!pager_is_disabled()) {
    return theme_pager($variables);
  }
  return '';
}
```

Where `pager_is_disabled()` is a function you write that determines the current status. You could store that info in static vars, a Drupal variable, database, cache, whatever makes most sense for your use case.